# How do I win wizard duels?

Tags: nintendo-ds, lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

I am playing the NDS version of Harry Potter Years 5-7 (specifically, Year 5: Chapter 3 - The Weasley Twins Leave Hogwarts) and I am at the point where I have to duel some people (I honestly can't tell precisely who - Sytherins? Possibly Malfoy and his cronies? It's hard for me to tell.).

Problem is, I know -how- to duel (point in either direction and press X to cast a spell, try to hit the other person so they run out of health first) - but I can't actually manage to win the duel - it seems that no matter what I do (cast quickly, or cast slower and build the spell strength) I lose the battle, and have to duel over and over again with no result.

Without winning, I apparently cannot get any farther in the story.

What am I missing here? What sort of strategy is successful?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see DS duelling seems a bit hit and miss. The way I win duels is to sometimes deflect spells <kbd>B</kbd> and then hopefully this will stun the opponent.

Once stunned, cast spells at them - hold <kbd>Y</kbd> for a split second; the longer you hold it the more powerful the spell (I think).  Anyway, don't hold it so long that it goes to red as I find no spell gets cast then.  I've managed to hit an opponent four or five times running (taking half a heart each time) by pressing <kbd>Y</kbd> just a little longer than a quick tap.

I can't see any sure fire way to win, and was looking for tips myself.

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! That is actually very helpful and your tips got me past that duel. :)

Comment: That is so odd, given that you pretty much have to put the controller down to lose a duel in the PS3 version.

Comment: @JasonBerkhan I am discovering that the DS version is pretty different from the major console versions, and not for the better. :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the basic game principles are the same between consoles, in the Wii version you have a ring around you and the person you are duelling. The colour of your opponents half of the ring indicates what colour spell you should cast. For example, if their half of the ring is white then you cast the lumos spell (one with the white icon in your spell list). There is also a shield you can use to protect against their attacks (again, this is the wii version I am talking about but I don't expect much to differ in the game mechanics)

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network :)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not at all how it works in the DS version - there is no way to choose which spell you cast, for example.